# Changing file name to the user's name PHP

Tags: php, file, upload

Instead of the file name being what the users want to name it, I would like the file name to be the user's username. As you can see in the code below, I got the user's username from the session. Now, I would just like to apply it to $_FILES, but replacing $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"] with just $username didn't happen to work. I'm not sure what  I did wrong, so I changed it back. Please take a look.

**upload.php**

```
<?php
include("functions.php");
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['username'];

$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        goTo("home.php");
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You should be able to set `$target_file = $target_dir . $username;`. Besides the filename, does the code work as you would expect? If not, something else might be wrong.

Comment: And grab this from your code: $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION); to tack an extension on the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your `$target_file` variable to the name you want, since this is what gets passed into `move_uploaded_file()`. I don't see anywhere in your code where you actually set this variable to their username (right now it's still using the name they selected when they uploaded it).

Without modifying your existing code too much, it looks like you can do this:

`$target_file = $target_dir . $username . '.' . $imageFileType;`

Answer (score 2):

Enter the following code before the move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file):

Added Code:

```
//Here we will get the extension of the file being uploaded
$temp = explode(".",$_FILES["file"]["name"]);

//Here we provide the new name and append the extension
$target_file = $username.'.'.end($temp);
```

Result:
When you call    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)    the     $target_file name will be the name we assigned to the $_target_file.